# Sum result of this 4 selects in one

Tags: mysql, select

I would like to shorten this 4 selects in one if possible or just sum all of the select results

```
SELECT COUNT(igrac2) FROM tekma
WHERE igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1<golovi2

SELECT COUNT(igrac2) FROM tekma
WHERE igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 and penali=2


SELECT COUNT(igrac1) FROM tekma
WHERE igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1>golovi2

SELECT COUNT(igrac1) FROM tekma
WHERE igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 AND penali=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 < golovi2, 1, 0)) +
    SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 = golovi2 and penali = 2, 1, 0)) +
    SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 > golovi2, 1, 0)) +
    SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 = golovi2 AND penali = 1, 1, 0))
FROM tekma
WHERE (igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 < golovi2)
  OR (igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 = golovi2 and penali = 2)
  OR (igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 > golovi2)
  OR (igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1 = golovi2 AND penali = 1)
```

The WHERE clause is optional as far as getting a valid result in this case, but if your table is large and the number of matching results is small, it would be beneficial to leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional sum as

```
select
sum( case when igrac2 = 'Dony' and golovi1<golovi2 then 1 else 0 end) as sum1,
sum( case when igrac2 = 'Dony' and golovi1=golovi2 and penali=2 then 1 else 0 end) as sum2,
sum( case when igrac2 = 'Dony' and golovi1>golovi2 then 1 else 0 end) as sum3,
sum( case when igrac2 = 'Dony' and golovi1=golovi2 and penali=1 then 1 else 0 end) as sum4
from tekma
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1<golovi2, 1, 0)) AS count1,
  SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 and penali=2)) AS count2,
  SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1>golovi2, 1,0)) AS count3,
  SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 AND penali=1, 1,0)) AS count4
FROM tekma
```

To get total count:

```
SELECT 
  (SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1<golovi2, 1, 0)) +
  SUM(IF(igrac2 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 and penali=2)) +
  SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1>golovi2, 1,0)) +
  SUM(IF(igrac1 LIKE "Dony" AND golovi1=golovi2 AND penali=1, 1,0))) AS totalCount
FROM tekma
```